# Creating Service from Executable (INSTSRV.EXE and SRVANY.EXE) Error - "Service started and then stopped"

Tags: windows-services, registry, exe, srvany, instsrv

I am trying to create a service on Windows using my own executable. When I try to start the service, I get the error message:

> "The  service on Local Computer started and then
> stopped. Some services stop automatically if they have no work to
> do..."

The exe should always be doing work because it is constantly running a timer that checks the time and makes database backups at certain points during the day. I have tested the executable on its own (not as a service) and it works fine.

I created the service using a batch file and INSTSRV.EXE and SRVANY.EXE. The batch file looks like this:

```
start /d "C:\<exe directory>" INSTSRV.EXE <service name> "C:\<exe
directory>\SRVANY.EXE"
```

The server name now shows up in my list of services on my computer. I also edited the registry to make sure everything was in order. Here is what my regedit entry looks like:

```
    Service key

DisplayName     REG_SZ          <service name>
ErrorControl    REG_DWORD       0
ImagePath       REG_EXPAND_SZ   "C:\<exe directory>\SRVANY.EXE" <service name> C:\<exe directory>\SRVANY.EXE
ObjectName      REG_SZ          LocalSystem
Start           REG_DWORD       2
Type            REG_DWORD       16

    Parameters key

AppDirectory    REG_SZ  E:\<exe directory>\
Application     REG_SZ  E:\<exe directory>\<exe file name>
```

I have used a similar batch file before to make a service from an executable, and I have compared the registry entries of that service with my own service's registry entries. They are pretty identical. I don't know why my service doesn't want to start.

Comment: Given the answer, I think this question can be closed as Typo/Unrepro.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your ImagePath value is incorrect. It should just contain the full path to the Srvany executable, and no more.

Indeed, when I have Srvany and Instsrv in "C:\Apps\Win2K3RK" and run:

```
C:\Apps\Win2K3RK\Instsrv.exe MyService C:\Apps\Win2K3RK\srvany.exe
```

the registry key created looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I actually tried without the second half of the ImagePath and that had no effect. I found my problem though, it was simply that I had forgotten a letter in the name of the executable in the Application key. Sorry for the trouble!

Answer (score 1):

I incorrectly named the executable in the Application key path. Woops! Sorry for the trouble guys.